# Aplicar estilo CSS a SweetAlert2 en Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

Estoy tratando de hacer unas notificaciones de correo electrónicos con *SweetAlert* en *React*, pero encuentro difícil aplicarles estilos CSS personalizados. Busco en la documentación y no encuentro mucho.

Por ejemplo, me debería quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en cambio me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sería bueno es que alguien me pueda indicar como puedo hacer para alargar el ancho del botón de confirmar, como cambiarle el tamaño y tipo de letra. También, ¿cómo puedo ponerle la propiedad `border-radius` para encoger los bordes de la notificación?.

Gracias y que tengan buen día!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes emplear clases personalizada para el elemento, en este caso confirmButton, para ello utilizas el valor [customClass](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass) y luego en tu archivo css crear la clase a utilizar para ese elemento y aplicas los estilos necesarios acompañados del valor `!important` para que se apliquen sobre los que tiene por defecto sweetalert de la siguiente manera:

```js
Swal.fire({
      showCloseButton: true,
      icon: "success",
      text: "Te hemos enviado un correo",
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'custom-button',
      },
    });
```

y tu clase CSS:

```
.custom-button {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
  width: 190px !important;
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el Playground por [aca](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dsvpcg?file=src/App.js) para que veas el resultado

---

### UPDATE 1

En base a tu pregunta *"que propiedad debería meter dentro de customClass para el texto"*, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

El CSS a utilizar es el siguiente:

```
.custom-container {
  color: purple !important;
}
```

Opcion 1:

Pasar una clase personalizada al contenedor `htmlContainer`:

```js
Swal.fire({
      showCloseButton: true,
      icon: "success",
      text: "Te hemos enviado un correo",
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'custom-button',
        htmlContainer: 'custom-container'
      },
    });
```

Opcion 2:

Utilizar el valor `html` en lugar de `text` para utilizar etiquetas html a las cuales les asignaras la clase css:

```js
Swal.fire({
      showCloseButton: true,
      icon: "success",
      html: '<p class="custom-container">Te hemos enviado un correo</p>',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'custom-button',
      },
    });
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias colega!

Comment: Una ultima pregunta que propiedad deberia meter dentro de custom class para el texto?

Comment: Cual texto? el del boton, el del contenido, el del titulo, define que texto quieres modificar

Comment: Revisa la actualizacion para ver si se ajusta a lo que preguntabas!

Comment: Me refiero a la de parte que dice: "Te hemos enviado un correo de verificacion para restablecer tu contraseña" que propiedad debria usar para alterarla? como la del el boton que era "customButton" cual deberia ser la de el texto?

Comment: Te la deje en la actualización que hice a la respuesta, revisala!

Comment: Ah si! No lo habia notado. Muhas graias amigo y disculpa la molestia. Soy Trainee y no manejo mucho esto.